# MonacoEditor trigger errors action menu manually

Tags: visual-studio-code, monaco-editor

Is it possible to trigger this menu to show so that it's not only errors that makes it pop up?
I know you can trigger the quickFix with
`editor.trigger("anystring", "editor.action.quickfix", payload)` but i cant find how to trigger this one.
https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.39.0#example-extending-language-services-model-markers-example

[image: example]

Comment: ok found it it's the action "editor.action.showHover" but when you move the mouse it immediately hides because you are not hovering errors